# Question regarding the use of なのに

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

What does the なのに mean in this sentence from Makino and Tsutsui's A Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar:

> アパートの家賃を払うのが精一杯**なのに**、まして（や）家を買うなんて夢物語だ

Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar translation:

"I am just managing to pay the rent for my apartment; how much more of a dream it is to imagine buying my own house!"

This entry is teaching まして which I understand, I fathom that the なの is simply used for emphasis, and the に in its use as a sentence final to indicate sympathy or regret (Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar p. 234).  Am I right in thinking this or is it something else?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're thinking too much. のに is [a particle](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172162/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB/) that is often translated
into "while, with [*some contrary condition*]". Since it derives from nominalizer の, nouns and na-adjectives that come before it should put な (< copula だ) at the end.

An interesting fact about ましてや is that, the antecedent can be stated with both から and のに.

> アパートの家賃を払うのが精一杯なのに、まして家を買うなんて夢物語だ
>
> アパートの家賃を払うのが精一杯なのだから、まして家を買うなんて夢物語だ